# Casting implementation to the interface with generic type

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

My company has a shared library that has code like this

```
public interface IBaseService<TBaseUser> where TBaseUser : BaseUser
{
   // snip
}

public class User : BaseUser
{
    // snip
}

public class SomeService : IBaseService<User>
{

}
```

Various applications make use of this shared code. I am trying to write a base controller that takes in an `IBaseService<BaseUser>` in its ctor.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController(IBaseService<BaseUser> service)
    { 
    }
}
```

The code at the library level works exactly as I'd expect, but when I try to use it from a consuming application and pass in the derived type, i.e. a `Service` type, it fails with an invalid cast.

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
    public MyController(SomeService service) : base(service)
    {
    }
}
```

Is what I want to do possible?

Comment: It sounds like your interface needs to be covariant... `IBaseService<out TBaseUser>`. That will fail to compile if any of the methods use `TBaseUser` as an input position, of course...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks - I neglected to mention covariance - I can't make it covariant as the interface uses TBaseUser for both return & input values.

Comment: In that case, SomeService simply doesn't implement `IBaseService<BaseUser>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `IBaseService`-iterface needs to be [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee207183.aspx):

```
interface IBaseService<out T>
```

This way you can assign an instance of `IBaseService<User>` to `IBaseService<BaseUser>`.